# Programmatically get function arguments (without **kwargs)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following function:

```
def test(* p1=None, p2=None):
  ...
```

Called as follows:

```
test(p2="hello")
```

Can I programmatically obtain a list/dictionary of the arguments and their value at runtime?

1: Don't want to use `**kwargs` because I want to force the user to use the proper argument names (and plan to do type annotation as well).

2: I've looked at the `inspect` module for getting the defaults, but does not seem to let me see the run-time values.

Looking to create code something like this:

```
request = {k: v for k,v in __some_magic_location__ if v is not None}
```

Comment: `* p1=None` is a SyntaxError. Did you mean `*, p1=None`?

Comment: Can you modify the definition of the `test` function?

Comment: So, in that case, would you want an output of `{"p2": "hello"}` or `{"p1": None, "p2": "hello"}?`

Comment: A pity it's closed now, but I don't want to un-dupe-hammer it open, either. Just wanted to suggest using a decorator `def deco(f): def _f(**kwargs): print("PARAMS:", kwargs) return f(**kwargs) return _f` and then `@deco def test(...)`; this way, you can use `kwargs` to print the arguments, and at the same time prevent the user from passing invalid keyword-arguments or arguments without a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [locals](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#locals):

```
>>> def test(*, p1=None, p2=None):
...     return locals()
...
>>> test(p2='hello')
{'p1': None, 'p2': 'hello'}
```

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that OP **cannot** change `test`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The OP said they "don't want to use **kwargs", so I think this is exactly what they want.

Comment: @Rawing You have a point there. This problem just seems too trivial in this case.

Comment: What is the `*` for?

Comment: Yes, I can change test. Had just never run across 'locals' before.

The "*" is a Python3 syntax indicating that all the arguments after it need to be passed by name, not position.

Comment: Also, if you use locals() within a class method, you need to filter out the 'self' entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inspect.getcallargs`:

```
import inspect
def test(*, p1=None, p2=None):
  pass

print(inspect.getcallargs(test, p2 = 'Hello'))
```

Output:

```
{'p2': 'Hello', 'p1': None}
```